# File doesn't always upload to server using PHP & Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ipad, safari

I have a page that I use to have users press a submit button to insert MYSQL data but also capture an image and upload a .png file to a directory all from the click of one submit button. 9/10 this works perfectly. I'm not sure if it's a connectivity issue (it's being done on a wireless device) or if it's my code. That 1/10 times it will INSERT the MYSQL data but it will not upload the image to the server. Below is my upload code from my file and the upload_data.php file that the code calls. Sorry my formatting on this site isn't the greatest.

```
 <script>
        function uploadEx() {
            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvasSignature");
            var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            document.getElementById('hidden_data').value = dataURL;
            var fd = new FormData(document.forms["form"]);

            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', '/inc/img/inspection/upload_data.php', true);

            xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
                if (e.lengthComputable) {
                    var percentComplete = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
                    console.log(percentComplete + '% uploaded');
                  //alert('Succesfully uploaded');
                }
            };

            xhr.onload = function() {

            };
            xhr.send(fd);
        };
    </script>


BELOW IS UPLOAD_DATA.PHP
<?php
$upload_dir = "upload/";
$img = $_POST['hidden_data'];
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$data = base64_decode($img);
$id = $_POST['sub_id'];
$file = $upload_dir . $id . ".png";
$success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
print $success ? $file : 'Unable to save the file.';
?>
```

Comment: Are you cancelling the default form submit event? Perhaps your request does not finish processing when the page is reloaded.

Comment: I didn't even realize that I have an onsubmit="uploadEx(); in my form tag and an onclick="uploadEx(); for my submit button. Perhaps that is the culprit. I'll have to do some testing though before I can rule that out.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment, you are not cancelling the default submit event and that would cause the form to be submitted. And that could cause the ajax request to not finish always.

If you use inline javascript like you do (I would try to move all inline js to the script itself...), you need to make sure that you use something like:

```
onsubmit="return uploadEx();"
```

and

```
onclick="return uploadEx();"
```

And in your `uploadEx()` function you end with:

```
function uploadEx() {
  // your code

  return false;
}
```

Comment: I will surely test this. Would I need to call my function with both my onsubmit and my onlick then?

Comment: @magowan90 If your button submits the form, you only need to check for `onsubmit`.

Comment: That's what I figured I just wanted to ensure this. Thank you.

Comment: I added the return false; to the javascript function and changed my onsubmit and onclick options. <form onsubmit="uploadEx(); return true;" name="form" id="form" accept-charset="utf-8" method="post">    <input align="center" type ="submit" name="submit" onclick="uploadEx(); return true;"></input>      This did not fix it. I submitted about 60 times. out of the 60, 2 of them failed. Also, it appears it won't run at all without the return true inside of my onclick and onsubmit.